# Vue & robots.txt. Как скрыть разделы сайта и проверить результат?

Tags: vue.js, seo, vue3, robots.txt, meta

Нужно скрыть раздел сайта [www.site-name.com/#/en/terms](http://www.site-name.com/#/en/terms) от индексации поисковиками, остальные оставить доступными. Как можно это сделать и проверить результат?

Сайт на Vue3 (Options API), используется vue-router, в url присутствует #.
Пробовал плагины vue-meta, vue-head, @vueuse/head но они все не работают. Выдаёт разные типы ошибок и сайт локально вообще не запускается (yarn run dev).
В robots.txt знак # это начало комментария, поэтому не получится прописать правила для одной страницы.

Содержимое файла robotx.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

В App.vue добавлен код, но не знаю будет ли он работать:

```
watch:  {
  $route: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(to, from) {
      const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="robots"]');
      const isNoindexPage = this.$route.fullPath.includes('terms');
      const tagValue = isNoindexPage ? 'noindex' : 'all';
      meta.setAttribute("content", tagValue);
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Попробуй вместо # использовать %23

Comment: @ВикторКарев К сожалению, не работает